# How can my method accept any type of Number, as a method argument? (Java generics)

Tags: java, generics

My CustomNumber class extends the Number class (implements all the method, but not listed here). The class has a division method, which should work as the following: I can give to it any type of Number argument, and always get a the calculation without precision loss. That is why I'm thinking about double values. But in this case, I can't call this method with anything else, but Double Objects. How can I make this method, any maybe the whole class 100% generic?

```
public class CustomNumber<T> extends java.lang.Number {

    java.lang.Number value;

    public CustomNumber(java.lang.Number value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static CustomNumber<Double> division(Number a, Number b) {
        return new CustomNumber<>(a.doubleValue() / b.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: For "no precision loss" division you probably want to use `BigDecimal` instead of `Double`, and disregard any `CustomNumber` implementation altogether.

Comment: I don't get this at all. It seems like you have a generic wrapper for Number, though I don't understand why you'd ever need this, and then a static method to return a CustomNumber<Double> why???

Comment: You don’t need generics for this. You aren’t using `T` anywhere in your code anyway.

Comment: What do you mean “I can't call this method with anything else, but `Double` objects”? What happens when you try? Please quote any error messages and/or stack trace precisely. It looks to me like it should work.

Comment: Let me say that, if you use the Double datatype as result, the "calculation without precision loss" goes away. You should use, at least, a [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class as returned value.

Comment: @Mena and others, I guess the asker is referring to the precision loss from integer division, e.g., 5 / 3 = 1, and that something close to 1.666667 will be OK in the example.

Comment: I just want to be able to call the method with any type of Number, and return a CustomNumber Object which can be any type, for example CustomNumber<BigDecimal>.

Comment: That is never going to be that simple. You need to do division in the target type to get its precision, and the syntax for double division is different from `BigDecimal` division, so one code line will never cover all. Let alone some user-defined `Number` subclass that you don’t know of and which may not support division at all.

Comment: Also if you want to specify that your static `division` method should return for example `CustomNumber<BigDecimal>`, it would require the *method* to be generic, not the class.

Comment: To complicate matters, `BigDecimal` has 10 divide methods (counting `divideAndRemainder()` and `divideToIntegralValue()` in) and it’s not obvious to me which one of them you will want to use.

Answer (score 1):

In this respect, Java is extremely annoying.

They dogmatically disallowed operator overloading (although Scala has it), so you are compelled to code `/` into a method called `divide` or similar, and so on.

For more specifics see how the arbitrary precision libraries such as `BigInteger` are implemented, and base your solution from that.

One a plus point in Java, you might get away with using `BigDecimal` and doing away with your idea entirely. Although the code you end up with when performing complex mathematical operations with it is practically unreadable. (For this reason I resort to using C++ with a JNI).

Comment: From its inception, Java’s goal was to have code that is [easy to read.](http://web.archive.org/web/20041211032713/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/hamilton_qa2.html)  Operator overloading is the opposite of that, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If this was what you were trying, it doesn’t work:

```
    CustomNumber<Integer> quotient = division(5, 3);
```

We get “Type mismatch: cannot convert from `CustomNumber<Double>` to `CustomNumber<Integer>`”. For an obvious reason. Even though the numbers you tried to divide were autoboxed into `Integer`.

The straightforward solution is to drop the generics completely:

```
public class CustomNumber extends java.lang.Number {

    // ...

    public static CustomNumber division(Number a, Number b) {
        return new CustomNumber(a.doubleValue() / b.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

Now we have no problem doing:

```
    CustomNumber quotient = division(5, 3);
    System.out.println(quotient);
```

With an appropriate `toString` method in your class this should print:

```
1.6666666666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.Number` offers very few methods. Division, for instance, doesn't really do the same thing for each type. `1.0d/2.0d` is `0.5d` but `1/2` is `0`. So you're going have to decide which you're doing. Also note the `double` does not exactly represent `long` or, say, `BigInteger`.

To map various forms of numbers to your common interpretation, you'll need an adapter layer. There may be ore than one way to map a numeric type.

```
public interface CustomNumber<THIS extends CustomNumber<THIS>> {
    THIS divide(THIS other);
}

public final class LongNumber extends CustomNumber<LongNumber> {
    // (Note, you don't actually need to overload this,
    //    but it does prevent the likes of LongNumber.of(aDouble).)
    public static LongNumber of(Long value) {
        return new LongNumber(value);
    }
    public static LongNumber of(AtomicLong value) {
        return new LongNumber(value);
    }

    private final Number value;

    private LongNumber(Number value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override public LongNumber divide(LongNumber other) {
        return this.longValue() / other.longValue();
    }
}
```

You might want to have an adapter for the same types that deal with, say, bankers' rounding. I don't want to even think about how to implement that. Or full on saturated arithmetic. So here's is a sign preserving alternative implementation (still does division by zero):

```
    @Override public SignPreservingLongNumber divide(
        SignPreservingLongNumber other
    ) {
        long dividend = this.longValue();
        long divisor = other.longValue();
        return (
            dividend == Long.MIN_VALUE &&
            divisor == -1
        ) ? Long.MAX_VALUE : dividend/divisor;
    }
```